# Android JNI/C. What is the syntax for calling dalvik native functions dvm_dalvik_system_DexFile[]?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

Building on this original post [How can I include proper include files for using libdvm.so at my shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766774/how-can-i-include-proper-include-files-for-using-libdvm-so-at-my-shared-library)

I need to call the native 'openDexFile' function defined in the structure dvm_dalvik_system_DexFile[] within the file dalvik/vm/native/dalvik_system_DexFile.cpp.  The implementation is in the library libdvm.so.

```
const DalvikNativeMethod dvm_dalvik_system_DexFile[] =
{ 
{ "openDexFile", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)I", Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_openDexFile },
{ "openDexFile", "([B)I", Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_openDexFile_bytearray },
{ "closeDexFile", "(I)V", Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_closeDexFile },
{ "defineClass", "Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;I)Ljava/lang/Class;", Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_defineClass },
{ "getClassNameList",   "(I)[Ljava/lang/String;", Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_getClassNameList },
{ "isDexOptNeeded",     "(Ljava/lang/String;)Z", Dalvik_dalvik_system_DexFile_isDexOptNeeded },
{ NULL, NULL, NULL },
};`
```

I was able to find something similar in Appendex "A" of this write-up http://net.cs.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/plohmann/2012-Schulz-Code_Protection_in_Android.pdf but it fails to compile for me.  I have not been able to locate JNI defines (types) for the writer's references to "u4", "ArrayObject", or the all important "dvm_dalvik_system_DexFile" as defined above.

What is the format for calling these native methods from JNI?

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed in the google AOSP code tree.  Including these files (with a few minor tweeks) got my code to complile.

```
#include "DexProto.h"   
#include "Object.h"     
#include "Native.h"
```